# Can I get internet on my Android phone through a usb cable connected to my Mac? (no wifi)

Tags: mac, android, tethering

I have an Android phone (OnePlus3) and I would like it to be able to connect to the internet through a USB cable connected to a Mac (which is connected to the internet with an Eth cable)

is that possible and how?

Comment: If you search for "USB Reverse Tethering", you will find articles that explain the procedure. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494  There is also an app for the Android side that may automate some of the steps for you.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free&hl=en